# Post array values in mysql database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel, rest

I'm developing rest api in laravel, here im trying to post array data in database, but i could not figure out how to do it, can some one guide me in this ? i'm new to laravel

ProductdetaisController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\productdetails;
class ProductdetailsController extends Controller{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return productdetails::all();
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'productname' => 'required',
        'productid' => 'required',
        'productdescription' => 'required',
        'productimage' => 'required',
        'productinvoice' => 'required',
    ]);
    return productdetails::create($request->all());
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return productdetails::find($id);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $productdetails = productdetails::find($id);
    return $productdetails->update($request->all());
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    return productdetails::find($id)->delete();
}
}
```

productdetails.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class productdetails extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['productname', 'productid', 'productdescription', 'productimage', 'productinvoice'];
}
```

2021_09_25_075455_create_productdetails_table.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateProductdetailsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('productdetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('productname');
        $table->string('productid');
        $table->string('productdescription');
        $table->array('productinvoice'); <----- here i want to store array of data ------>
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('productdetails');
}
}
```

example for array of data

**[{productquantity: '5', productprice: '5', productgst: '5', productname: 'xyz'}, {productquantity: '5', productprice: '5', productgst: '5', productname: 'ABC'}]**

How to post such kind of above data in the data base ?

Comment: `here i want to store array of data` No DONT EVEN THINK OF THAT AS A SOLUTION. There are many reasons for no doing this, but just imagine your site gets busy and you sell 10000's of this product. Imagine the hassle finding a specific invoice??

Comment: Check out a basic Relational database design tutorial and refactor your database to use proper normalised structures

Comment: @RiggsFolly what solution you would suggest for this kind of problem ?

Comment: ALso pretty sure there is no `array` data type in eloquent

Comment: @RiggsFolly we can go with json data type but im not sure how to go with it.

Comment: I would avoid that as well to be honest,

Comment: then what solution you would suggest ?

Comment: Well I cannot think of a good reason to have any knowledge of an invoice in a ProductDetail object, so I would not have that information in this structure

Answer (score 0):

`Model::create()` doesn't work like that. You should loop over the array and create rows individually.

[Laravel docs on this method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts)

Also, your validation won't work. [Docs on array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (save it to database)

```
$productinvoice  =json_encode( $request->your_array_json_data );
```

...save it to database.
When you want to use It inside client side You should parse It to array of json data.
Like this: (use it inside client side part)

```
JSON.parse($productinvoice)
```

When You want to use it inside backend part after retrieve it from database.
This is how You could convert it to php array : (use it inside backend part)

```
$productinvoice = json_decode($productionDetails->productinvoice, true);
```